# Mongoose & mongoDB with nested queries

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm passing a query that I did in mongoDB to mongoose and it gives me error.

The query in mongo DB is:

```
db.facturas.find({
    _id: { 
        $in: db.detalles.distinct("id_factura", { 
            category: ObjectId("5889eae21ffcc6da2c6b4ae4")
        })
    }
})
```

In the APP I build the query like this:

```
Factura.find({'_id': { "$in" : Detalle.distinct("id_factura",{qrycat}) } })
        .populate('pto_venta')
        .populate('forma_pago')
        .exec(function(err, result) {
          if (err) res.send(err);
          res.json(result); 
        });
```

And I get the following error in NODEJS:

> /var/nodejs/aadides-sgi/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:242
>    var body = JSON.stringify(val, replacer, spaces);
>                   ^
>
> TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
>      at Object.stringify (native)
>      at ServerResponse.json (/var/nodejs/aadides-sgi/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:242:19)
>      at ServerResponse.send (/var/nodejs/aadides-sgi/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:151:21)
>      at /var/nodejs/aadides-sgi/app/handlers/facturasHandler.js:494:22
>      at /var/nodejs/aadides-sgi/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:2176:21
>      at /var/nodejs/aadides-sgi/node_modules/kareem/index.js:160:11
>      at Query._find (/var/nodejs/aadides-sgi/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:1019:5)
>      at /var/nodejs/aadides-sgi/node_modules/kareem/index.js:156:8
>      at /var/nodejs/aadides-sgi/node_modules/kareem/index.js:18:7
>      at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
>      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
>   events.js:160
>        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>        ^
>
> Error: read ECONNRESET
>      at exports._errnoException (util.js:1018:11)
>      at Pipe.onread (net.js:568:26)

Comment: try `...).populate('forma_pago').lean().exec(...`; I guess you are trying to return what the find give to you right through Express, and it do not like to convert the mongoose object into String

Comment: Does `Detalle.distinct("id_factura",{qrycat})` return an Array, because the `$in` operator selects where a value equals any value in a specified array. e.g. `{ qty: { $in: [ 5, 15 ] } }`

Comment: @akinjide No it wouldn't since mongoose operations are asynchronous.

Comment: What is `{qrycat}` ?

Answer (score 0):

Double-check your second argument for [distinct()](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-distinct) as `{qrycat}` doesn't look like a valid object.

More importantly, `distinct()` is asynchronous (like most mongoose operations) so you need have a callback to get the IDs before calling your next operation.

```
Detalle.distinct("id_factura", {qrycat}, function (err, id_facturas) {
    if (err) 
        return res.send(err);
    // id_facturas should be an array
    Factura.find({'_id': { $in: id_facturas }})
        .populate('pto_venta forma_pago') // Mongoose >= 3.6
        .exec(function(err, result) {
            if (err) 
                return res.send(err); // don't forget the return
            res.json(result); 
        });
});
```

Comment: qrycat is a json object with ObjectID of category
{
category: '5889eae21ffcc6da2c6b4ae4'
}